# Cursor of X axis in MS Chart Control gives the number of point

Tags: c#, mschart

Here is my code to plot something on the chart control:

```
    private Random random = new Random();
    int gg = 0;

    private void plotChart1()
    {
        columns[0] = 0.01*gg++.ToString();
        columns[1] = random.Next(1, 50).ToString();    

        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(columns[0], columns[1]);

        chart1.ResetAutoValues();
        chart1.Invalidate();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plotChart1();
    }
```

The axes are automatically updated. I can get the coordinates of clicked point by MouseClick event or CursorPositionChanged event. Both gives me the same result.

The Y value is correct, but the X value of the clicked point gives me the number of point, not its value. If you look at the code above: At the 5th tick of timer, 0.05 is written to the X axis. If I click on that point, I get 5. It is like an index value of the point. How can I get X value of any point?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. When I checked the Xvalue and Yvalue properties of `chart1.Series[0].Points` by debugging, I have noticed that all Xvalue were zero, though x values were displayed on chart. I have passed double values instead of string to `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY()` method. It is solved.

As a side note: `chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed value` should be set to `false`.